# ATtiny85 and INPUT_PULLUP

Tags: attiny, input, pull-up

I have read some conflicting sources about what pins have internal pullup resistors available for the Attiny85 microcontroller. Can all I/O pins work with INPUT_PULLUP, or just some of them? And if so, which ones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the datasheet, probably just search for "internal" or "pullup" [image] I believe there are little more pins/ports as portB, so they should all have internal pull ups.